# Power Automate: "When a work item is created" (DevOps) NOT WORKING

Tags: devops, power-automate

Created a very simple flow.
Both tried triggers "When a task is created" and "When a task is updated". Both have the same errors. They working for you guys?
Tried 2 different projects in DevOps, same error...

```
TF212023: You cannot compare fields with different data types in the WHERE clause of a work item query. 
The error is caused by «[System.CreatedDate] >= '2022-02-14T12.47.21.8023045Z'».
Azure DevOps ActivityId: 17164780-ae50-46b7-ae5e-secret....
Details: {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"TF212023: 
You cannot compare fields with different data types in the WHERE clause of a work item query. 
The error is caused by «[System.CreatedDate] >= '2022-02-14T12.47.21.8023045Z'».",
"typeName":"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssPropertyValidationException, 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=secret....","typeKey":"VssPropertyValidationException",
"errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}
clientRequestId: secret....
```

[image: My flow:]

Answer (score 0):

i have a same problem, i just re-create my task in power automate and after that everything work fine

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31626924)